# Could not find or load main class in vs code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

The case:

I have created a complex java project (spring boot) with maven build in IntelliJ and I was able to run it, everything was working fine. Now, as IntelliJ hasn't a community edition with spring boot, I had to move to vs code. I didn't change anything in my project, I just opened the folder (which contains the pom.xml and the src folder) in vs code and let vs code load the java project (earlier I installed all the extensions like spring boot, java, etc. for vs code).

After vs code opened the project successfully, I wanted to run it in the main method by clicking the run text (I inserted the image, that you can see the folder structure):

[image: vs code image]

But as stated above, I get the famous error. I reloaded the window, I cleared the workspace, I set the JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH variables in the env variables and tried, tried, tried it again, but no success. What the hell can I do on top of that? It worked in IntelliJ, it should work in vs code too. I use java se17. Note, that if I start a new simple project, the program get's compiled and executed without any error.

Another curiosity is, if I try to load the maven dependencies, vs code says, that it can't create the dependency tree, but if I run the `mvn dependency:tree` command, I get all the dependencies and it says, that the build was successful.

What is going on here?

**EDIT:** my antivirus program blocked maven, so, the problem with the dependency tree is now gone, but the error with the classpath remains.

Comment: Why don't you just run it with the maven spring boot plugin? You could've continued to use IntelliJ (which IMO is a much better Java IDE than vscode)

Comment: My trial period is over, I can't even start IntelliJ anymore.

Comment: Regardless if what IDE you use, question is the same. Why don't you use the Spring Boot maven plugin to run it? The command line is your friend

Comment: Try this running your spring boot project in the command line with`mvn clean spring-boot:run`. If this works, then its a VS Code configuration problem.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked. What to do now? In the worst case, I have to set up the whole project from the beginning in vs code.